# Reload current view after network returns in ionic 4+Angular

Tags: angular, ionic4

We have an app written in ionic 4 and Angular. It has tabs at the bottom and views displaying in each tab. We are using the [network plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/network/) to detect if the app is offline or online. If the app is offline and we open the app, the network call fails to get data and the currently selected tab view shows network error message. If we now toggle the network to come online, the network error goes away but the page does not try and reload the data. Some options we can try:

1. We can add pull to refresh to all the pages.
2. We can add a subscriber for network state to all the views and then reload the views when app comes online.

But we wanted to know if there is a way to determine the currently displayed tab view and reload just that using window.reload or any router methods?

Comment: Can you add some code for the tabs and how are you detecting the online state?

Comment: you can call the REST api from the `ionViewWillEnter` lifecycle event hook in your component where you have the `Navcontroller`. It will be called every time when a tab becomes active